# ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED in couchdb only on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, couchdb

I have a VPS with a Couchdb v1.6.1 installed.

When i access *http://myhost.com:5984* it works fine.

After i configured ssl and try access *https://myhost.com:6984* i got `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` error only in chrome.

I already tested in Safari, Firefox, Opera, IE, curl, mobile browsers, and all works fine, only chrome not works.

Some idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

It like seems a problem with the **erlang's** version.

**CouchDB 1.6.1** uses **Erlang/OTP <= 17** and thats here the problem.

Then i found 2 solutions to get SSL working:

1. Tested with **Erlang/OTP 19** and got success.
2. Create a **nginx** proxy to **CouchDB**.